# Combine all previous columns to the current column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, window-functions, recursive-query

I have a table called terms and I am using SQL Server 2014

```
termID   termname
  1       term1
  2       term2
  3       term3
  4       term4
```

I would like to have the result like this

```
 termID   termname
  1         term1
  2         term1 and term2
  3         term1 and term2 and term3
  4         term1 and term2 and term3 and term4
```

I have done this using `LAG()`, but I am able to get the immediately previous value only. I need to get all the previous column values.

```
 select termid, CASE WHEN ISNULL(prev_word,'')<>'' THEN prev_word+' and '+ termname ELSE termname END
from (
    select termID, 
           lag(termname) over (order by termID) as prev_word,
           termname
    from terms
) as t
```

Comment: Which version are you on? `string_agg()`

Comment: hope u are asking about the SQLserver managemnet studio version.the version of  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is 12.0.5223.6 @shawnt00

Comment: No, I meant the server version. `select @@version` Anyway check if `string_agg()` is available on your platform.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
 Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Comment: STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL) Applies to: SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some database (such as Postgres) support `string_agg()` as a window function, which lets you write this as:

```
select
    temid,
    string_agg(termname, ' and ') over(order by termid) termname
from terms
```

... Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support this syntax (yet?).

An alternative is a recursive query. I will not assume that `termid` always start at `1` and always increments without gaps, so this starts by renumbering the rows with `row_number()`, then iteratively walks the dataset, accumating the strings step by step:

```
with 
    data as (
        select t.*, row_number() over(order by termid) rn from terms t
    ),
    cte as (
        select termid, cast(termname as varchar(max)) termname, rn
        from data 
        where rn = 1
        union all
        select d.termid, c.termname + ' and ' + d.termname, d.rn
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.rn = c.rn + 1
    )
select termid, termname from cte order by termid
```

If you have more than 100 values in the list, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query (otherwise it will hit the default limit of 100 iterations).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ab3f94b844248e258d8f5bfc17cdf6a)**:

```
termid | termname                           
-----: | :----------------------------------
     1 | term1                              
     2 | term1 and term2                    
     3 | term1 and term2 and term3          
     4 | term1 and term2 and term3 and term4
```